# I am not able to start ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

When i try to start my ejabberd server using following commond

> /etc/init.d/ejabberd start

it shows following but nothing starts when i fire www.example.com:5280\http-bind

> Starting ejabberd:                                         [  OK  ]

as my logs at ***/var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log*** are empty but to figure it out i tried running

> ejabberdctl live

and got following log ,i really don't know wht this says specially over here {error,duplicate_name} so can any please help me how to get rid off this and start ejabberd successfully.

```
{error_logger,{{2012,2,4},{14,28,18}},"Protocol: ~p: register error: ~p~n",["inet_tcp",{{badmatch,{error,duplicate_name}},[{inet_tcp_dist,listen,1},{net_kernel,start_protos,4},{net_kernel,start_protos,3},{net_kernel,init_node,2},{net_kernel,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,2,4},{14,28,18}},crash_report,[[{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,net_kernel},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.8.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.94>,<0.17.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,23},{reductions,484}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2012,2,4},{14,28,18}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfa,{net_kernel,start_link,[['ejabberd@example',shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,2,4},{14,28,18}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfa,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,2,4},{14,28,18}},crash_report,[[{pid,<0.7.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{ancestors,[<0.6.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.8.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.6.0>,<0.5.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,233},{stack_size,23},{reductions,123}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2012,2,4},{14,28,18}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/ejabberd/erl_crash_20120204-142801.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means you have already an ejabberd running, that is an Erlang node with the same name (Duplication name).
Stop / Kill your existing beam processes.